# Facebook Graph API caching JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, json, facebook-graph-api, caching

I am using Facebook Graph API to get contents from a Facebook fan page and then display them into a website. I am doing it like this, and it is working, but somehow, it seems that my hosting provider is limiting my requests every certain time.... So I would like to cache the response and only ask for a new request every 8h for example.

```
$data = get_data("https://graph.facebook.com/12345678/posts?access_token=1111112222233333&limit=20&fields=full_picture,link,message,likes,comments&date_format=U");
$result = json_decode($data);
```

The get_data function uses CURL in the following way:

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $datos = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $datos;
}
```

This works fine, I can output the JSON data response and use it as I like into my website to display the content. But as I mention, in my hosting, this seems to fail every X time, I guess because I am getting limited. I have tried to cache the response using some code I saw here at Stackoverflow. But I cannot figure out how to integrate and use both codes. I have managed to create the cache file, but I cannot manage to read correctly from the cached file and avoid making a new request to Facebook graph API.

```
// cache files are created like cache/abcdef123456...
    $cacheFile = 'cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5($url);

    if (file_exists($cacheFile)) {
        $fh = fopen($cacheFile, 'r');
        $cacheTime = trim(fgets($fh));

        // if data was cached recently, return cached data
        if ($cacheTime > strtotime('-60 minutes')) {
            return fread($fh);
        }

        // else delete cache file
        fclose($fh);
        unlink($cacheFile);
    }

$fh = fopen($cacheFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fh, time() . "\n");
    fwrite($fh, $json);
    fclose($fh);

return $json;
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Do you have evidence that suggests that your hosting provider is limiting your outbound connections (are you on shared hosting?)? It might be easier just to ask? It is also possible that Facebook is limiting your requests, but in that case, they would be indicating so in their responses. Does that every 1 out of x time the value of `$result` change and your code fails to process it because it lacks a property that you expect?

Comment: I would recommend to use memcache(d) like Mohammed Asif is suggesting, it's a nice and clean way to manage these things.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder No, I do not know for sure, but it is always working on localhost, and not in my free hosting, so I am pretty sure they are the ones limiting. Additionally, facebook response does not give any error. I just get something like max time request exceeded... and at that time, I try on localhost, and no problem at all :)

Comment: @qalbiol It sounds like your problem is that you're using free hosting (presumably sharing in IP with many other sites). If any of them make requests to Facebook's API as well, I would imagine that you'll all being rate limited together (FB might do per IP limiting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some thinks that could come in handy when trying to construct cache and to cache actual object (or even arrays).

The functions [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) allows you to get a string representation of an object or of an array so you can cache it as plain text and then pop the object/array as it was before from the string.

[`filectime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php) which allows you to get the last modification date of a file, so when it is created, you can rely on this information to see if your cache is outdated like you tried to implement it.

And for the whole working code, there you go :

```
function get_data($url) {
    /** @var $cache_file is path/to/the/cache/file/based/on/md5/url */
    $cache_file = 'cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5($url);
    if(file_exists($cache_file)){
        /** 
         * Using the last modification date of the cache file to check its validity 
         */
        if(filectime($cache_file) < strtotime('-60 minutes')){
            unlink($cache_file);
        } else {
            echo 'TRACE -- REMOVE ME -- out of cache';
            /** 
             * unserializing the object on the cache file 
             * so it gets is original "shape" : object, array, ...  
             */
            return unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_file));
        }
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    /** 
     * We actually did the curl call so we need to (re)create the cache file 
     * with the string representation of our curl return we got from serialize 
     */
    file_put_contents($cache_file, serialize($data));

    return $data;
}
```

**PS** : note that I changed the `$datos` variable on your actual function `get_data` to a more common `$data`.

Comment: Thanks @b.enoit.be, I was able to make it work and I am not experiencing problems any more with my hosting provider. Regards, E.

Answer (score 3):

This answer will add a few more dependencies to your project, but it may be well worth it instead of rolling your own stuff.

You could use the [Guzzle](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/index.html) HTTP client, coupled with the [HTTP Cache](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/plugins/cache-plugin.html) plugin.

```
$client = new Client('http://www.test.com/');

$cachePlugin = new CachePlugin(array(
    'storage' => new DefaultCacheStorage(
        new DoctrineCacheAdapter(
            new FilesystemCache('/path/to/cache/files')
        )
    )
));

$client->addSubscriber($cachePlugin);

$request = $client->get('https://graph.facebook.com/12345678/posts?access_token=1111112222233333&limit=20&fields=full_picture,link,message,likes,comments&date_format=U');
$request->getParams()->set('cache.override_ttl', 3600*8); // 8hrs

$data = $request->send()->getBody();
$result = json_decode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure is you can use memcache, if you can:

```
$cacheFile = 'cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5($url);
$mem = new Memcached();
$mem->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
$cached = $mem->get($cacheFile);
if($cached){
  return $cached;
}
else{
  $data = get_data($url);
  $mem->set($cacheFile, json_encode($data), time() + 60*10); //10 min
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your hosting provider is pushing all of your outbound requests through a proxy server -- you can try to defeat it by adding an extra parameter near the beginning of the request :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/12345678/posts?p=(randomstring)&access_token=1111112222233333&limit=20&fields=full_picture,link,message,likes,comments&date_format=U
```

I have used this successfully for outbound calls to third party data providers. Of course I don't know if your particular issue is this issue. You could also be bitten by the provider if they reject requests with parameters they don't expect.